# Understanding characters in a binary file

Tags: binary, hex, byte, bit

I am reading a binary file written in 16bits (little endian and signed).
I successfully read the file and got the good values from the conversion from bytes to integers. But there are some characters that I don't understand, so I hope that someone can explain me it :)

- b'\xff\xff' gives me -1 which is good and I understand that \x indicates a hexadecimal character escape.
- b'\x00\x00' gives 0, logic.
- b'v\x1d' gives 7542, which is the good value (I know it because I know the value that I should get and it is this one), but I don't understand the meaning of the 'v'. What is its signification? I have found on the web the ASCII - Binary Character Table in which 'v' is 01110110. If we consider this value for 'v' and '1d' as 00011101', then we have 01110110 00011101 which is not 7542 but 30237, so the 'v' is wrong here...
- b'K\x1d' gives 7499. Same here, the value is good but I do not understand the 'K'.

So if anyone can explain to me what is the meaning of the 'v' and the 'K' it would be great!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess regarding K and v is half right: as it's [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), your value will have least significant byte first:

- "v" is `76` in hex, so `v\x1d` = `1D76` in hex = `7542`
- "K" is `4B` in hex, so `K\x1d` = `1D4B` in hex = `7499`

Comment: Thank you very much onestep.ua!